# How to get .net core server name and options

Tags: c#, .net-core

I use c# .net core on linux. I want to see what server options and what server name I use. I know server name must be Kestrel and options must be something like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserveroptions?view=aspnetcore-1.1

But how to get this info in runtime?

Comment: just to clarify, you do have full access over the server, right ?

Comment: Yes, I have full access to server.

Comment: First thing would be to know how the server is run. for instance, if launched as a service, on Ubuntu (or other distro using systemd) you can have info here : https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/05/manage-kestrel-process-with-systemd.html . Does it help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Server information by injecting the [IServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.iserver?view=aspnetcore-3.1) service. Which will be the actual server instance running. From there you can access the `KestrelServerOptions` in the [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserver.options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServer_Options) property.
Here is a sample code snippet where I inject it in a controller and get the options.

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IServer webServer)
{
   _logger = logger;
   KestrelServer kestrelServer = webServer as KestrelServer;
   if (kestrelServer == null)
   {
      throw new Exception($"Not running inside Kestrel server. The current server type is {webServer.GetType().FullName}");
   }
   else
   {
      KestrelServerOptions kestrelServerOptions = kestrelServer.Options;
      // do something with the options
   }
}
```